# Python subprocess.call weird behavior with multiple calls

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to call remote (ssh) commands using the subprocess.call function like this.

```
import shlex
from subprocess import call
cmd1='ssh user@example.com mkdir temp'
cmd2='scp test.txt user@example.com:temp'

call(shlex.split(cmd1))
call(shlex.split(cmd2))
```

When I call the above, the mkdir does not seem to execute - although the documentation for subprocess.call says it waits for execution before returning. The latency of the individual ssh calls is about 0.5 seconds. It seems to work fine on the gigabit LAN where the latency is almost zero.

However it seems to work fine when the calls are made like this:

```
call(shlex.split(cmd1)) &  call(shlex.split(cmd2))
```

What is the problem with the first approach?

Thank you,
Miliana

Comment: This is weird, since there's no significant difference between the two pieces of code: the second example does some bitwise arithmetic with call() result values, but doesn't influence the calls themselves.  Have you tried stracing the script to see what it does?

Comment: Does it work if you replace `call` with `Popen`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't look for the result of call in the first method.

```
if call(shlex.split(cmd1))!=0:
    call(shlex.split(cmd2))
```

Comment: I tried this (checking for zero, nonzero return code) , but it doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: that strange it's exactly what do the second line `call(shlex.split(cmd1)) &  call(shlex.split(cmd2))`

Comment: obviously they arent exactly same implementation wise

Answer (score 0):

Your problematic version always works for me. I would think this is a network problem especially since you indicate that it works in gigabit LANs.